# Changing the base class of an Object dynamically in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, design-patterns

I have two classes Sensor1 & Sensor2 which inherits from class Sensor. I am creating class Camera for which the base class should be Sensor1 or Sensor2 based on some condition in the run-time. Is it possible?

One way is to create a pointer member for Sensor in Camera and then assign to Sensor1 or Sensor2 (based on condition) and in that case for all the methods of Sensor, I need to create the methods in Camera (setResolution & changeMode) and call the corresponding methods (which I want to avoid)

```
class Sensor {
 public:
       Sensor(){}
       ~Sensor(){}
       void setResolution(int w, int h) {};
       void changeMode(int mode) {};
}

class Sensor1: public Sensor {
  public:
       Sensor1(){}
       ~Sensor1(){}
       void setResolution(int w, int h) {\** change based on sensor **\}
       void changeMode(int mode) {\** sensor specific implementation **\}
}

class Sensor2: public Sensor {
   public:
       Sensor2(){}
       ~Sensor2(){}
       void setResolution(int w, int h) {\** change based on sensor **\}
       void changeMode(int mode) {\** sensor specific implementation **\}

class Camera: public Sensor {
   public:
       Camera (bool flag){
       //Change base class to either Sensor1 or Sensor2 which inherits from common base class Sensor
       }
       ~Camera(){}
}
```

Comment: C++ doesn't have [reflection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(computer_programming)). You can't change a base-class at run-time.

Comment: And I suggest you try to ask about the *actual* problem you have, not about how you want to solve it. [Related reading about the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: You could generate both using a template then choose which to create from a factory function or something. But you can't change the base class of an object.

Comment: Check out [Strategy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) and [State](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern) design patterns.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, Thank you. edited as per my problem.

Comment: Is there a method on Camera that is supposed to change the type after Camera is constructed? In your example it looks like you make the final decision in the constructor already. If that is true, using a factory should be sufficient for you.

Comment: Normally we say that a camera *has a* sensor. Saying that a camera *is a* sensor would be a bit of a stretch.

Comment: @n.m. Considering that in the OP, the classes were named A, B. C and D, it's actually pleasing how well your comment explains the merits of containment vs inheritance in this case. It shows how timeless good ideas are sometimes.

Comment: @n.m. It really makes sense.

Comment: Just be aware that real world facts don't necessarily map 1:1 to software :) so the real world has-a relationship is not the ultimate verdict, just one of the things to consider.

Comment: @n.m. Yes. Sure.

Comment: You can think of it as adapter as well but the implementation will be almost same as the answer by @CobusKruger

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a great place to use something like the [Strategy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) pattern.

Instead of changing your base class for `Camera`, let `Camera` contain a pointer to either `Sensor1` or `Sensor2`. That's where you check your condition.

If the two classes `Sensor1` and `Sensor2` inherit from a common base (like `Sensor`), the pattern is very simple to implement.

My C++ is a bit rusty, so see this as either code or pseudocode, depending on how valid it ends up being:

```
class Camera {
private:
  Sensor* obj;
public:
  Camera (bool flag){
    if (flag) {
      obj = new Sensor1();
    } else {
      obj = new Sensor2();
    }
  }
}
```

You could also provide functions (one for `Sensor1` and one for `Sensor2`) to cast the `obj` field to the correct type.

**About changing the base class**

Let's talk about *why* it's not possible to switch the base class and why it would be inadvisable even if you could.

Think of your class as a normal struct containing fields, plus a number of functions operating on a variable of that struct type, named `this`.

If you inherit from `Sensor1`, the struct for `Camera` would contain all the fields from `Sensor1` and all the fields from `Camera`. For argument's sake, let's say it all adds up to 42 bytes of memory. And let's say combining the fields from `Sensor2` with the fields from `Camera` adds up to 60 bytes.

Clearly, if you then dynamically change the base type, your memory size should change, but the allocation was already done by the time you enter the constructor. So if you could switch base types from `Sensor1` to `Sensor2` at the time, you would suddenly have 18 bytes too few and updating any of those would overwrite memory that is possibly allocated to something else. That's a disaster waiting to happen.

And so we use patterns like [Strategy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern), as I showed here. It's easier to reason about, simple to implement, widely understood and safe.

Comment: Brilliant answer !

Comment: Isn't the OP trying to avoid this strategy?

Comment: @SauravSahu Sure, but he asked if it could be done. The answer is no. I updated the answer to explain why it's not supported, and why it would be unwise even if you could.

Comment: @CobusKruger, Thanks for explanation. Could you share your thoughts on this link[https://terrainformatica.com/2010/08/12/cpp-how-to-change-class-of-object-in-runtime/]?

Comment: @GunasekaranSrinivasan I did a blog post a decade ago about changing the runtime class in Delphi. Notice all the disclaimers. I did it because it was possible, not because it is at all something to put in production code. I needed to take steps to ensure the in-memory layout is identical. In your case, you want to change the base class, which cannot be done in any mechanism I know of. Here is the blog post: https://sourcecodeadventures.wordpress.com/2009/07/13/hellishly-horrible-hack-1-changing-an-objects-functionality-without-recompiling/

Comment: Why is `camera` still derived from `Sensor` when its delegating everything to either `Sensor1` or `Sensor2' object? Shouldn't it be just by itself, not derived from amything?

Comment: @CobusKruger. Interesting information and nice explanation.

Answer (score 1):

To keep the function calls out of the `Camera` class, you can delegate the same task to another class, say `SensorOperator`. Make the `Camera` object *composed of* `Sensor` object. Now, in case any new class, say "Mobile", comes in which can have the same sensors, then we can use the same strategy with it.

```
template <typename T>
class SensorOperator : public Sensor {
private:
    T *t;
public:
    void setResolution(int w, int h) {
        t->setResolution(w, h);
    }
    void changeMode(int mode) { t->changeMode(mode); }
};
class Camera {
    public:
        Camera(bool flag) {
            //Change base class to either Sensor1 or Sensor2 which inherits from common base class Sensor
            if (flag) sensor = new SensorOperator<Sensor1>();
            else sensor = new SensorOperator<Sensor2>();

        }
        ~Camera() {}
    private:
        Sensor *sensor;
};
```

I would've preferred to implement the `Sensor` class as an abstract class. Also, prefer composition over inheritance in case of `Camera` class as the `Camera` might be many things other than just being a `Sensor`.

Comment: In my actual implementation, it's abstract class only (I should have updated it). And, I was planning to compose the Sensor class in Camera class. But I was worried about lot of methods in the Camera just for the sake of Sensor methods and yes, Camera is more than just being a Sensor. I posted the question just to find is there any way apart from writing wrapper methods for Sensor.